# How to stop footer from mooving when scroll page?

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML and have question about layout.
I'm trying to make a normal page footer. I mean, it should be on the bottom of page and not moving when the page is scrolled on mobile devices.
Text should be placed in the center of the footer.

I tried to solve it with `position: fixed` property, but it doesn't help.

Need some help, please.

My page looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/download/a/www/css/style_about.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="cont">
      <h1> Lorem </h1>
      <p> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
      </p>
      <h3> Credits</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="credits">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href="">Lorem</a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href="">Lorem</a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href="">Lorem</a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href="">Lorem</a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href="">Lorem</a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href="">Lorem</a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href="">Lorem</a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href="">Lorem</a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <?php include(realpath(__DIR__) . '/footer-confident.php'); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Styles and html layout I show in Codepen: https://codepen.io/h071/pen/rZoMbr

Comment: `position:fixed;` keeps the element "attached" to scroller, you should use `position:absolute` in order to keep it from following with scroller

Comment: @IdontReallywolf just changed to `absolute`, did nothing more. Footer is now appearing  on some distance from page top. Should I do smth more?

Comment: Try see https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page . There are quite a few ways to sticky a footer to the bottom of a page.

Comment: Fix and set the position : `position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px;`

Comment: btw, you've missed `}` before closing the `@media` rules for `.credits`

Comment: @Seblor did it. Footer now became sticked to the bottom of the page. But there are 2 problems: 1. `text-align: center` doesn't help centrifying footers's text now,
 2. In mobile devices footer is floating on the center of page before page's content. Added just the same rules for `.footer` in media query
`@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
}`

Comment: @IdontReallywolf thnks, added.

Comment: @aysee The footer is not centered because the div is croped to the inner element's size. You need to make it match the page's width. Add this rule : `right: 0px;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this to a new answer to not confuse other users.

If you want the footer at the bottom, regardless the content length (I hope this is what you want), you can do the following. The main content will always grow to fill at least the viewport height and push the footer to the bottom.

To test this out, you can change the min-height on the body to 200vh or something and it should push the footer further down.

If this is also not what you are trying to accomplish, I have no idea what you want, sorry...

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #c0ffee;
}

footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #bada55;
}
```

```html
<main class="content"></main>
<footer>Hi</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is `position: sticky` on your footer for mobile devices.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #c0ffee;
}

footer {
  width: 100vw;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #bada55;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
<footer>Hi</footer>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `position: sticky` is not supported by IE. *edit :* And it seems Safari needs the prefix `-webkit-` to make it work.

Comment: @Seblor correct, although it shouldn't matter when on a mobile device and if not supported, it just falls back to static which is also okay in most cases.

Comment: @Andifined excuse me, I've tryed correcting my styles according to your answer. A bit confused. May you look in my updated styles and tell me what did I do wrong?

Comment: Your wrap element has a width of 100vw and margin. Since the margin is added you get a scroll bar, if that is what you are referring to. Also you only really need `position: sticky` and `bottom: 0`, the rest was for showcase only :)

Comment: @Andifined don't understand. `body` element's margin is set to 0. `wrap` element's margin is left and right (need this margins). Keeping in mind this what should I do to solve my problem which is: a) make footer static and sticky on the bottom and b) keep this property in small screens. Now unfortunately it isn't..

Comment: @aysee Your pen works for me... The footer  stays in the viewport no matter on which screen size. Which browser are you using? Please check for your browser support on `position:sticky`: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: @Andifined, sorry for my bad English. I think, I couldn't explain my task clearly. I need footer to be at the bottom of the page...for example as it is in here in SO site - https://stackoverflow.com/  ...And I need this property to be both on destops and mobiles :)

Comment: I use Chrome v.69, but I try to find solution which is good enough for most common cases for Internet users

Comment: @aysee Check out my new answer, I hope it helps you :)

Answer (score -1):

you can try it with flexbox. make the page display: flex and the main content flex: 1, it forces the content to grow and take up the maximum allowable size. the footer can then have an assigned static height if you want, or its contents will determine its height.

It would look something like this:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/alexjackscss/pen/yxGbBK)